# Bootstrap modal in modal form issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The issue i am having is if I open a modal followed by changing the body to different form via `$.ajax`.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4PyP.png]

Basicly the `DeleteTaskObjectiveModal` calls the `EditTaskModal` which brings up a form in the `#MainModal`. Every form input is broken, on text I cannot enter anything and the `<select>`'s are the same as in the image.

It also slows down the right mouse click for some reason.

```
function DeleteTaskObjectiveModal(parent_url, delete_url, label, question){
            $('#MainModal').modal('hide');
            $('#DeletionLabel').html(label);
            $('#DeletionQuestion').html(question);
            $('#DeletionButton').attr('onclick', 'AjaxDelete("'+delete_url+'"); $("#MainModal").modal("hide"); EditTaskModal("'+parent_url+'");');
            $('#DeletionModal').modal('show');
            $('#DeletionModal').unbind('click').on('click', '.DeletionClose', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            EditTaskModal(parent_url);
                    });
    }

function EditTaskModal(edit_url){
    $.ajax({
        url: edit_url
    }).done(function(value) {
                    $('#MainModalLabel').html('Edit Task');
                    $('#MainModalBody').html(value);
                    $('#MainModal').modal('show');
                    $('.MainModalClose').attr('onclick', '$("#MainModal").modal("hide"); ContentAjax("{{ URL::to("TaskList") }}");');
            });
    }
```

Comment: If you have the answer you should answer the question.

Comment: Seems like you just figured it out. I would suggest using one modal and just changing the content of the modal instead of creating another one which will cause undesirable output.

Comment: +1 Good question, just always remember to not edit the question with the answer! =) See [self-answering on SO's Faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I didn't have enough reputation at the time to self-answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this problem is to make sure that all modals are closed before opening another one.